# Excel Power Query and manual entry

Tags: excel, vba, merge, powerquery

In Excel, I have created a table through a series of queries that shows all the equipment awaiting calibration in my lab.  And then through VBA assigned technicians to certain equipment. That part works GREAT.  The part that I need help with is when that table refreshes.  It is set to refresh every hour, but when it does it clears out my "Assigned Technician" column.  If I run the VBA macro again, it will assign items differently than before.

So I want the table to refresh, but I want it to not overwrite the "Assigned Technician" column with a null value (which it keeps doing). I've creating a copy of the first table which will hold on to the manually entered Tech names, and then merging the "Assigned Tech" column back into the original after the refresh, but it is not working right.  I am guessing because the second table is a reference of the first, so I cant merge a dependent table back into the parent table.  Is there a way that I can do this without creating a ridiculous amount of tables and queries that I am just going to hide from the user in the end?

I am sorry if I am not using the right jargon or verbiage.  I don't use this skill set that often.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you. TL;DR: This isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue. As you've written your question, nobody but you would even have the slightest idea where to start to help you...

Comment: FreeMan is right - without showing us some data, or the macro code, we'll have no idea where to start helping you.

Comment: I think you're trying something similar to [what this person was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860598/values-hard-coded-after-power-query-runs-is-dislocated-when-data-source-updates/50861832#50861832). See @MarcelBeug's answer to [this earlier posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653178/inserting-text-manually-in-a-custom-column-and-should-be-visible-on-refresh-of-t/40656881#406568). He includes this [link to a good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duNYHfvP_8U&feature=youtu.be) that he made to show how it's done.

Comment: Marc Pincince that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.