# Input data into a table generated from Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am pulling data from multiple spreadsheets into a table using power query, generating a table of the following format:

| Date | Description | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | £1,000 |
| 2 | b | £2,000 |
| 3 | c | £3,000 |

I want to manually enter data into a fourth 'fee' column (as set out below) each month. When I come to refresh the query in the following month I want to ensure that the 'Fee' data will still correspond with the relevant month.

| Date | Description | Revenue | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | £1,000 | £1,500 |
| 2 | b | £2,000 | £2,500 |
| 3 | c | £3,000 | £3,000 |

Comment: Refer this query --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653178/inserting-text-manually-in-a-custom-column-and-should-be-visible-on-refresh-of-t   by @MarcelBeug

Comment: Here is an explanation of how its done --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duNYHfvP_8U

Comment: Brilliant - exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank to the person who created. MarcelBeug Sir !